# Pipe using observable not getting expected result

Tags: angular

I have a pipe that load image blob url through api based on image name.

```
 export class LoadingImageNamePipe implements PipeTransform {

   imageSub: Subscription;
   constructor(private getimage: GetFileService) {}

   transform(name: any) {
     return this.getimageurl(name);
   }


   result: BehaviorSubject < string > = new BehaviorSubject < string > ('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1000" height="300"><rect width="1000" height="1000" style="fill:rgb(189, 189, 189)"/></svg>');

   getimageurl(name: string) {
     this.imageSub = this.getimage.GetFile(name) !.subscribe(x => {
         this.result.next(( < any > x).changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity);
     });
     return this.result;
   }

   ngOnDestroy()
   {
     this.imageSub.unsubscribe();
   }

}
```

and I have used above pipe in template to load different image

```
  <img class="card-img-top sampul" [src]="imagename_1 | loadImageName | async">
  <img class="card-img-top sampul" [src]="imagename_2 | loadImageName | async">
```

the service for getting url is Ok, two different image have different url.

the problem is that loadImageName pipe results in same url.

Is BehaviorSubject updating all same pipe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `component` in angular, `pipe` will be constructed only once and share the same instance when used in multiple places.

Since you subscribed from `loadImageName` in multiple places, your behaviorsubject `result` will emit value to both of them when its value changed which result in sample url in view **because they share the same behaviorsubject**.

---

And since your `this.getimage.GetFile` already returns an observable, you can simple return it directly instead, also you don't need to unsubscribe when using `AsyncPipe`.

```
getimageurl(name: string) {
  return this.getimage.GetFile(name).pipe(map(x => ( < any > x).changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity));
}
```

Comment: i just move behaviorsubject inside getimageurl, is it still same instance ?, i just try it and working ?

Comment: @DwiYanuarIlham no, if you move it into function, it will be created per time the function is called.